# Circular dependency best practice

Tags: c#

What is the best way to solve this.

I have projects the following projects:

> Model
>
> Logic (references model)
>
> Synchronization (references both model and logic)
>
> Web (references all projects)

All runs fine, the web project fires the synchronization project, which uses model and logic, and does it's work.
But now, some times, the logic project also has to call a method in the synchronization project, but this reference cannot be added because of the circular dependency that is not allowed.

What would be the easiest way to make this whole thing work?

A bit more on the synchronization project.
Synchronization works on it's own. It runs processes that bring data from an external database to the database in my application. It does this by creating objects based on the model and saves them by using the logic.
This works fine, and gives us the ability to simply create another synchronization project/assembly that could do the same thing, but targeted at a completely different type of database.

The problem is, that we now, from time to time, want to call a method in the sychronization project to update some data in the other direction / to the external database.

Comment: What is synchronization doing?

Comment: I've updated my question with some explanation of the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it's time to refactor. The easiest is to break the pieces neded in both Synchronization and Logic out into a fifth project and reference that in both. However, like most easy things, this can also be a sign that you need to rethink how you've allocated your code in the first place. It may be that the code needed by Logic in Synchronization belongs in Logic in the first place.

Comment: I've updated my question, explaining a bit more what the synchronization does. The point is that we want to keep that sync.project separated from the rest. This project communicates with an external database. And if we keep everything in that project, we can easily create one other, similar project, that does the same for another type of database/web service.

Comment: Then I'd question why Synchronization needs to reference Logic. You might benefit by making Synchronization dumber--make it just about the transport back and forth. Check out the places where Synchronization accesses Logic and evaluate whether those pieces wouldn't fit better elsewhere. All you really need to Synchronize is the foreign data and how to fit it into the local Model.

Comment: Hi Jacob, It will take a lot of work, but i like the idea of making the whole thing dumber. So i'm going for this route. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. Something wrong and you have to refactor wrong dependencies/references
2. The time to introduce new project called smth like Common (assuming you already have 4 pretty high level projects I would bet for #1 - try to figure out why Synchronizaiton references logic and logic references synchronization in the same time)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project "`NewProject`" and put that method "or the class that is holding it" in that it, and then add it as a reference to `Synchronization` and `Logic`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not move the method that Logic needs to the Logic project?  Synchronization can then call the method in Logic, since it references Logic.

Of course, I'm assuming there isn't a whole bunch of other code in Synchronization that this method requires.  If there is, then perhaps it's time for a fifth project, perhaps called something like "Utility" or "Common".

There's also the possibility that Synchronization and Logic both need similar methods but not quite the same, in which case you make two separate methods, one in each project.